# Сдвинуть кнопку при наведении курсора на неё

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот в чём заключается задача: 
На Python нужно написать программу. Используя Tkinter нужно создать label по центру и по бокам 2 кнопки(side=TOP,LEFT,RIGHT), причём одна кнопка должна быть с особой command. Эта команда должна сделать следующее: при попадании курсора на кнопку - эта кнопка должна перескочить на другую координату, данный процесс должен быть циклическим. Другими словами пользователь не должен успевать нажимать на эту кнопку, но может нажать на другую (обездвиженную).Проблема именно в двигающейся кнопке. Надеюсь, что объяснил доходчиво. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Объяснил доходчиво. Тут за тебя твои домашки делать никто не будет. Придется напрячься самому. Надеюсь, что объяснил доходчиво.

Comment: @Эникейщик, нормальный же вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy какой вопрос?

Comment: @Эникейщик, этот. Как сделать бегающую кнопку.

Comment: @Qwertiy заявлено, что есть какая-то проблема. В чем именно проблема - непонятно. А программки с прыгающей кнопкой еще в 90-х на дискетках ходили.

Comment: @Эникейщик К сожалению для вас это не моя домашняя работа.  Возможно я просто не правильно поставил вопрос. Я самостоятельно изучаю данную тему. И я просто хотел узнать, как примерно это должно было выглядеть. Мне не нужно создавать все виджеты модуля tkinter. Вообще эту идею я решил взять по одному видео. Там выглядело это примерно так... в label писалось Вы довольны своей зарплатой? В углу, но на экране была картинка сбербанка. И на кнопку "нет" нажать было нельзя. Пользователь не успевал сделать этого. И оставалось нажимать только "Да". После чего выводится сообщение: "Мы и не сомневались".

Comment: @Pavel К сожалению для вас я не сожалею Как примерно должно выглядеть **что**? Ешьте слона частями.

Comment: Я могу скинуть источник, [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YySQizYSDs] Это должно выглядеть примерно так. Ещё раз повторюсь, что мне не нужен весь код. Меня интересует сама кнопка, её передвижение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно так:

```
def move_btn(btn):
    '''Функция двигает кнопку в левый верхний угол. '''
    btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn = Button(text='Бегающая кнопка')
btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: move_btn(btn))
```

Answer (score 0):

И так, спасибо предыдущим комментаторам, на просторах интернета наткнулся на подобную вещь, и всё-таки я думаю, что более рациональным будет сделать так:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def move():
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    moving_button.place_configure(relx=x, rely=y)

root = tk.Tk()

moving_button = tk.Button(root, text='Click Me', command=move)

moving_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

Этот код имеет следующий функционал: при *нажатии* на кнопку она будет перескакивать в любую точку окна